Getting Typescript error when passing Component and Component's props as a prop
I'm currently working on creating a Popover component that accepts a TriggerComponent as a prop. The TriggerComponent can either be a Link or a Button (both are custom components in my case), and their respective props are defined as LinkProp and ButtonProp.
What I'm aiming for is to create a generic interface in TypeScript that ensures if a user passes Link as the TriggerComponent, only Link-specific props should be allowed inside restTriggerProps. Similarly, if they pass Button, only Button-specific props should be accepted.
I have tried so many different ways to solve this, but I keep getting different errors.
For the below code, I am gettign this error : 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ children: string; download?: any; href?: string | undefined; hrefLang?: string | undefined; media?: string | undefined; ping?: string | undefined; target?: HTMLAttributeAnchorTarget | undefined; ... 268 more ...; value?: string | ... 2 more ... | undefined; }'

interface Props<T> {
  children?: ReactNode
  triggerLabel: string
  TriggerComponent: FC<T>
  restTriggerProps?: T & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> &
      ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
}

export const Popover = <T,>({
  TriggerComponent,
  triggerLabel,
  restTriggerProps,
  children,
}:Props<T>) => {
  const [showPopover, setShowPopover] = useState(false)

  const onToggle = () => {
    setShowPopover((prev) => !prev)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <TriggerComponent
        onClick={onToggle}        
        {...restTriggerProps}
      >
        {triggerLabel}
      </TriggerComponent>
      {showPopover && (
        <div
          className="popover-content"       
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}



If anyone wants to figure out this. Here is the solution found in Discord
Solution : Typescript Playground
Solution Explanation : Discord Channel
